# Particular solution of a Ricatti ODE satisfying initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I want to solve the following Ricatti ODE: $y′ = (y −t)^2 + 1, y(0) = 2$ but I am unable to find a particular solution that will satisfy the initial condition. I found solutions to the equation (say, $y = t$), but none of them satisfy $y(0)=2$. Any hints as to how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$y′ = (y −t)^2 + 1, y(0) = 2$$
$$(y-t)′ = (y −t)^2 $$
$$z′ = z^2 $$
Where $z=y-t$.
The DE is separable.

---

Edit:
$$\dfrac {z'}{z^2}=1$$
Integrate:
$$-\dfrac 1 z =t+c$$
$$\dfrac 1 {y-t}=-t+C$$
Apply initial condition:
$$y(0)=2 \implies  C= \dfrac 12$$
The solution is therefore:
$$\dfrac {1}{y-t}+t=\dfrac 12$$
$$y(t)=\dfrac {2}{1-2t}+t$$

Comment: I am just slightly confused. I solved it to get y = t - 2/(2t-1). This is a particular solution. But in this problem, since we are given the initial value, won't we only get a particular solution. I mean, isn't this the solution itself? I thought I would need to write the solution as y = y_b + y_p where y_b is the solution to the bernoulli equation.

Comment: I added more line I hope it's more clear now  @SC  Yes it's the solution to the IVP  It's the general solution not the particular one that should satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know that. Then, we can also take y_p(t) = t as a particular solution and then proceed with solving for the ricatti ODE as y = y_b + y_p. Here of course, we don’t need it as it’s separable. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @SC and yes you can use $y_p=t$ as a particular solution to solve the DE then apply initial condition to find the value of the constant.